# How do I escape a single quote in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

How can I escape a `'` (single quote) in Presto?

This is where I am trying to use it

```sql
select count(*) as count 
from uploads
where title not in ('Driver's License')
```

I've tried the usual escapes: , `'Driver\'s License'`, `"Driver's License"`, `E'Driver\'s License'` but nothing seems to work. Presto's docs are vague. Anyone know?

Comment: In (standard) SQL it would be `'Driver''s License'`

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

The answer, provided by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), is to use another `'`.

`'Driver''s License'`

Answer (score 3):

Put a single quotes two times in place of single quotes, which you need to escape:

```
select count(*) as count 
from uploads
where title not in ('Driver''s License')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CHR(39)` character function anywhere you need a single quote. Use with either the `concat` function or using double pipe `||`:

```
select count(*) as count 
from uploads
where title not in (concat('Driver', CHR(39), 's License'))
```

**or**

```
select count(*) as count 
from uploads
where title not in ('Driver' || CHR(39) || 's License')
```